# What is the issue in below sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, mysql-workbench

I am beginner in sql. Anyone please tell me the problem of my customised query.

```sql
select * 
from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_hospital_registration h 
INNER JOIN Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages s 
      ON  s.hospitalId = h.id 
      AND s.active = 1 
      AND ( select max(sp.expireDate), sp.hospitalId 
            from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages sp
            where sp.active = 1 
            group by sp.hospitalId ) 
where h.hospital_active = 1
```

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Subscription table

```
hospital Id expireDate
145         2021-07-10
146         2021-06-10
147         2021-09-10
146         2021-10-10
```

Comment: What the subquery in ON clause must do? it gives a 2-column rowset - a lot of rows 2 column each,- whereas single scalar value (which may be treated as some boolean) must be used in ON.

Comment: Why do you need a subquery in a ON clause?

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares for selecting max(exp.date) for that hospitals(ie. there is one to many relation)

Comment: Then, I'd add this subquery in a new INNER JOIN clause, like the answer just posted

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares i added, but hospital 146 is returning 2 times. ie, it s not taking max(exp.date)

Comment: "scalar subquery" PS [mre] [ask] [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put that subquery with the max and group by inside an INNER JOIN clause.

```
select * 
from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_hospital_registration h 
INNER JOIN ( select max(sp.expireDate) maxexpiredate, sp.hospitalId 
            from Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages sp
            where sp.active = 1 
            group by sp.hospitalId ) as s 
      ON  s.hospitalId = h.id 
where h.hospital_active = 1
```

Since I don't have your data tables, I made up one environment to test that query by using table variables. The example below is for SQL Server, but the query works fine for MySQL, which currently I don't have installed on my machine.

```
declare @tbl_subscribed_packages TABLE(
  hospitalId int, 
  active bit, 
  expiredate datetime
)

declare @tbl_hospital_registration table(
 id int,
 hospital_active bit)
```

Now populate tables with data:

```
insert @tbl_hospital_registration 
values (145,1),(146,1),(147,1)

insert @tbl_subscribed_packages 
values (145,1,'2021-07-10')
,(146,1,'2021-06-10')
,(147,1,'2021-09-10')
,(146,1,'2021-10-10')
```

Then, I test the query against these data

```
select * 
from @tbl_hospital_registration h 
INNER JOIN ( select max(sp.expireDate) maxexpiredate, sp.hospitalId 
            from @tbl_subscribed_packages sp
            where sp.active = 1 
            group by sp.hospitalId ) as s 
      ON  s.hospitalId = h.id 
where h.hospital_active = 1
```

Note that using subquery as a view in INNER JOIN, I should add an alias name for max(expireDate) column.
The result is:

| id | hospital_active | maxexpiredate | hospitalId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 1 | 2021-07-10 00:00:00.000 | 145 |
| 146 | 1 | 2021-10-10 00:00:00.000 | 146 |
| 147 | 1 | 2021-09-10 00:00:00.000 | 147 |

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, its working fine...thank u

Answer (score 0):

6th line has issues. After AND you should have condition but you have sub query returns two column values

Comment: can you update that query?

Comment: you did not mention what's your requirement. Please update what's your requirement and how do you want to see the result ( with output columns)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below - using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
    select *,row_number() over(partition by s.hospitalId order by expireDate desc ) as rn from 
    Follow_My_Doct.tbl_hospital_registration h INNER JOIN Follow_My_Doct.tbl_subscribed_packages s 
    ON s.hospitalId = h.id 
    where h.hospital_active = 1 and s.active = 1 
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: This query returning same hospital in multiple time(2 time) , i need only max(exp.date) of that hospital

Comment: please check my subscription table in update question.
executing your query it's 146 row is coming 2 times

Comment: @Bueno, I've updated the answer - you can check now

Comment: Still also returning hospital id 146 row 2 times. I need to return only max(exp.date).ie, it will return hospital only one(Id 146)

Comment: using row_number() something sql syntax error :)

Comment: @Bueno, what is the error

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Fahmi Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'